# Should I expect PDF vs TIF CMYK images to render differently on screen?

Tags: pdf-reader, color-profiles, image-viewer, evince, cmyk

Consider a TIF CMYK image with embedded ICC profile, e.g. using ImageMagick :

```
convert input.tif -profile /path/to/ISOcoated_v2_eci.icc output.pdf
convert input.tif -profile /path/to/ISOcoated_v2_eci.icc output.tif
convert input.tif -profile /path/to/ISOcoated_v2_eci.icc output.jpg
```

The color rendering on screen between the PDF version viewed with `evince` or `mupdf` and the TIF/JPG versions viewed with `eog` or `gpicview` are quite different.

I understand from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288263/why-cmyk-colors-are-displayed-wrong-on-screen) and [this bug report](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=97103) that PDF viewers using `poppler` might have a different CMYK onscreen color rendering than other programs.  Using `mupdf` leads to the same color rendering, but of course it could simply be that `mupdf` follows the same convention as other PDF viewers.

So is such a difference expected ?

Answer (score 0):

Converting back from the PDF to TIF or JPG, the final file renders onscreen with the same colors as the original one, so I guess this is just a rendering issue indeed.

A better answer would provide insights on why image viewers and PDF viewers follow different conventions, and confirm or infirm that such conventions are followed by all or most programs.  No time to dig further right now, but for the records [PDF specifications](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) (section 8.6 Colour Spaces, p.138) may probably help.